# Darktable: How to edit the same image as multiple different edit versions?

Tags: file-management, darktable

In Darktable, you can only import the same image once as image.jpg for example. What if we would like to work on and make multiple edited versions of image.jpg instead, and produce multiple different sidecar files containing alternative edit histories for them in the process to compare later for choosing one in the end? (Without copy and pasting image.jpg into its directory multiple times with different names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for [Duplicate manager](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/3.8/en/module-reference/utility-modules/darkroom/duplicate-manager/) in Darktable. According to the text you can:

> View and create multiple versions of the current image. Each version
> can be edited independently without affecting other versions – all
> versions use the same underlying image file, but the editing history
> of each version is stored in its own independent XMP sidecar file.